# firefox extension breaks when using export?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

im working on this addon for firefox, and i came upon some issue i cant figure out how to resolve:

on file1.js, which is the 'master script' i run the following code, for testing:

```
document.body.style.border = "5px solid red";
console.log("extension ran");
alert("test")
```

and it all works well. now, I'd like to run a function from file2.js file i have in the same folder, like so:

```
import {createCheckBox} from "./file2.js"
createCheckBox();
```

where on file2.js the function is implemented like so:

```
export function createCheckBox(){
   //code
}
```

however, when i add that import, nothing on the extension works, not even the alert and the console log that previously worked, so i know im missing something and that the exporting breaks the extension somehow, but i don't know why or how to fix it.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is to list all of your [content scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts) in [the manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_scripts) as such:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    matches: [...],
    js: ['file2.js', 'file1.js']
  }
]
```

This way, all functions in `file2.js` are available in `file1.js` without any importing. You also don't need to `export` them.

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_scripts):

> Files are injected in the order given. This means that, for example, if you include jQuery here followed by another content script, like this:
>
> `"js": ["jquery.js", "my-content-script.js"]`
>
> Then, "my-content-script.js" can use jQuery.

Comment: after looking at other extension's source code after posting this, i realized this is the best solution which actually worked, thank you!